# Waveforms for a given ideal inverters Circuit?

Tags: waveform

I have the following circuit. All the inverters are ideal CMOS.

[image]

I need to draw the waveforms for each point (A, B, D, E, Vo).
Let's assume that my waveform at Vi is:

[image]

What will be the wavefrom at point A, B, D, E, Vo ??

**Edited:**
Well thank you for your help!! 
I managed to solve this problem.
Here is the solution:(Sorry for the bad quality of my images and for my bad english!!)
[image]

Comment: When you say "inverter", are you referring to a linear circuit (gain = -1) or a digital circuit (gain = -infinity)? In the latter case, do you know what the switching threshold is? Is it Vdd/2?

Comment: First, use proper component designators.  You have three components labeled R and two labeled C.  That makes it hard to talk about your circuit.  Second, this is basically a edge-to-glitch converter with a delay.  Can you see why?

Comment: Also, you don't show any time scale on your input signal. Do you understand why this might be relevant, especially relative to 1/RC?

Comment: @DaveTweed - most likely neither.  A "classroom inverter" typically has finite gain because they want you to see that it is unresponsive below vil or above vih and somewhat linear in between.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a homework question to me so **no full answer**, just pointers.

Firstly, as Olin correctly points out, each component should be properly designated and, as Dave correctly points out, described so that there is no confusion. As there are no actual values mentioned you can only answer this question in terms of time constants (1 time constant, T (seconds) = C (farads) x R (ohms))

[image]

*Gates 1 - 3 are CMOS digital inverter gates with a threshold of 1/2 supply voltage.*

As to waveforms R1C1 is a simple RC  delay circuit

R2 is simply a load on the output of G1

C2R3 form a simple CR  circuit that is used for edge detection. (Normally there's a diode across R3 to clamp the leading edge spike to prevent damage to the gate input.)

The outputs of G1, G2 and G3 will be logic levels (either 0 or Vs - where Vs is the supply voltage to the logic gates) and will switch when the input crosses the Vs/2 threshold.

Google will provide your answers.